# No se me muestra la lista de los productos añadidos con el formulario

Tags: angular

Al guardar un nuevo producto o usuario con mis formularios para productos o usuarios, en la vista no se me muestran los objetos, pero en la consola si me aparece el array con los objetos guardados en la base de datos... (No me da ningún error, en la consola se me muestra el objeto, pero en la vista nada) El código es el siguiente:

EL SERVICIO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL CONTROLADOR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y LA VISTA :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL NAVEGADOR :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor cambia todas las imágenes por código. De lo contrario tu pregunta no será bien recibida. Una imagen puede ayudar en ciertos modos. Pero no podemos copiar y pegar código de una imagen para reproducir tu escenario. Por otro lado, cambia la etiqueta, no es `angularjs` es sólo `angular`. Saludos

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Recuerda proporcionarnos un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Esas capturas de pantalla nos impiden reproducir el problema con sencillez. Por favor, copia y pega el código en tu pregunta editándola en [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/340443/edit) en vez de compartir capturas de pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Era una tontería al final. En el constructor en la parte del response tuve que quitar `resonse.producto` y dejarlo solo en response y  poner:

```
this.cosas = response.cosas ;
```